# what are the changes in HTTP request format while migrating from Dialogflow v1 to Dialogflow v2

Tags: dialogflow-es

The below python code is what I am using as a http request to query dialogflow-V1.I want to migrate to v2.But I am facing issues when I changed parameters with respect to v2 naming.

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN'
}

params = (
    ('v', '20150910'),
    ('lang', 'en'),
    ('query', 'query_str'),
    ('sessionId', "10000"), #UNIQUE ID
    ('timezone', 'America/New_York'),
    )

response = requests.get('https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query', headers=headers, params=params)
```

**Help me migrate the above DFv1 code to DFv2 format**
below is what I tried

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer #Client access token'
}

params = (
    ('queryInput.text.languageCode ', 'en'),
    ('detectIntent', 'query_str'),
    ('session', 'projects/your-project-id/agent/sessions/session-id'),  
    ('queryParams.timeZone ', 'America/New_York'),
    )

response = requests.get('https://api.dialogflow.com/v2/query', headers=headers, params=params)
```

I am not sure of what exactly is session id in DFv2.The response here is not is any format as expected.Below is the response

```
b'Dialogflow@-moz-keyframes blink {0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}@-webkit-keyframes blink {0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}@-ms-keyframes blink {0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}@keyframes blink {0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}@-moz-keyframes fadein {from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}@-webkit-keyframes fadein{from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}@-ms-keyframes fadein {from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}@keyframes fadein {from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}#loading-screen{background: #fff; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 999999; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease; transition: opacity 500ms ease;}#loading-screen #logo {display: block; width: 109px; height: 39px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(\'https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/common/assets/img/logo@2x-black.png\'); background-size: contain; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -20px 0 0 -55px; -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out; -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out; transition:all 1s ease-in-out; -moz-animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; -webkit-animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; -ms-animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out; animation:blink normal 2s infinite ease-in-out;}#loading-screen #assistant-preview {width: 400px; height: 200px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -120px 0 0 -200px; text-align: center; background: white; -webkit-animation: fadein 500ms; -moz-animation: fadein 500ms; -ms-animation: fadein 500ms; animation: fadein 500ms;}#loading-screen #assistant-preview .logo {width: 46px; height: 46px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(\'https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/common/assets/img/logo_icon_48dp.png\'); background-size: contain; position: absolute; left:45%;}#loading-screen #assistant-preview .title {margin-top: 100px; font-size: 23px;}#loading-screen #assistant-preview .progress-container {margin: 25px 50px;}#loading-screen #assistant-preview .progress-container md-progress-linear, #loading-screen #assistant-preview .progress-container md-progress-linear .md-container, #loading-screen #assistant-preview .progress-container md-progress-linear .md-bar, #loading-screen #assistant-preview .progress-container md-progress-linear .md-dashed {height: 2px;}window.INTERNALIZED = true; window.DF_FLAGS = {email: "", backend: "https:\\/\\/api.dialogflow.com", opBackend: "https:\\/\\/dialogflow.clients6.google.com", apiKey: "xxxxx",}; window.saveAs = undefined; window.i18n = undefined; window.d3 = undefined; window.addStyleString = function(str){var node = document.createElement(\'style\'); node.innerHTML = str; document.head.appendChild(node);};window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag(\'js\', new Date()); gtag(\'config\', \'UA-98266305-2\'); gtag(\'config\', \'UA-98266305-8\');Updating Actions on Google...var loadDeferredStyles = function() {var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles"); var replacement = document.createElement("div"); replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent; document.body.appendChild(replacement); addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);}; var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame; if (raf) {raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });} else {window.addEventListener(\'load\', loadDeferredStyles);}if (window.location.hash.endsWith(\'assistant_preview\')) {setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById(\'assistant-preview\').style.display = \'block\';}, 200);} else {document.getElementById(\'logo\').style.display = \'block\';}window.WIZ_global_data = {"nQyAE":{"EtBwpb":"false","He6Wuc":"false","xJW1Ve":"true","tm22M":"false","aVzR2d":"false","ox9Ggd":"false","Dk1LPb":"false","CXZ8Fd":"false","c9LSR":"true","tvMknd":"true","eiw7Vc":"false","tLPClf":"false","lAsnAb":"false","buULxf":"false","adjIR":"false"}};var AF_initDataKeys = []\n; var AF_dataServiceRequests = {}; var AF_initDataChunkQueue = []; var AF_initDataCallback; var AF_initDataInitializeCallback; if (AF_initDataInitializeCallback) {AF_initDataInitializeCallback(AF_initDataKeys, AF_initDataChunkQueue, AF_dataServiceRequests);}if (!AF_initDataCallback) {AF_initDataCallback = function(chunk) {AF_initDataChunkQueue.push(chunk);};}'
```

Please help me resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: You say the response looks like junk, but you don't include it. Updating your question to include the response could help us help you figure out your problem.

Comment: I have updated the response above,please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move from v1 to v2 is not that straightforward. There are a number of things you need to address. The "query" API call has changed to the [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) API call. This has a lot of consequences.

The first is that the URL path has dramatically changed. Consult the reference page linked above, but it needs to be something more like

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/agent/sessions/SESSION_ID:detectIntent
```

It also needs to be an HTTPS POST request - you can't use GET anymore.

Moving to POST also means that the request body is more complicated. While v1 had most of the parameters in the top level of a JSON structure, v2 has these in nested JSON objects. So although the [migration guide](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-api#query_to_detectintent) says that "timezone" is replaced with "queryParams.timeZone", this really means that your JSON response would need to have a structure including

```
{
  ...
  "queryParams": {
    ...
      "timeZone": "America/NewYork"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

As you note in the comments, the biggest change is how you need to do [auth](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup). Instead of using a single shared secret, as you did with v1, you need to get a Google Cloud Service Account and use the secret from that account to generate an access token, which usually has a limited time to live. The good news is that the Google Cloud libraries or SDK will generate (and sometimes manage) the access token for you.

Comment: Okay thanks! In V1 authentication can be done with client access token also but in v2 the authentication is only done with the json/Access token and access token will expire every one hour .Is it so?can you conifirm?

Comment: You're certainly welcome. If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. Broadly speaking, that is correct about auth. You need to use a service account and generate an access token from the service account credentials. Usually those access tokens have a limited time. (I've updated the answer with some references.)